# Адаптивность скрипта

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть следующая строка в скрипте:

```
$('#timeline').css('margin-left', -(num-1)*10 + "%"); //сдвигаем таймлан на текущую точку*ширину элемента влево
```

Мне нужно, чтобы на ширине меньше 1200px вместо 10 давалось 5, меньше 962px - 0, к примеру. То есть как медиа запросы в CSS, только в JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать так: вводим вместо `10` переменную и определяем ее в зависимости от размера экрана:

```js
var vari;

function variChange(winWidth) {
  if (winWidth > 1200) {
    vari = 10;
  }
  if (winWidth <= 1200 && winWidth > 962) {
    vari = 5;
  }
  if (winWidth <= 962) {
    vari = 0;
  }
  console.log(vari); // для демонстрации
}
variChange($(window).width()); // $(window).width() - ширина экрана
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Также можно продублировать вызов функции определения переменной в событие `.resize()` - тогда переменная будет изменяться при непосредственном изменении размера экрана.

```js
var vari;

function variChange(winWidth) {
  if (winWidth > 1200) {
    vari = 10;
  }
  if (winWidth <= 1200 && winWidth > 962) {
    vari = 5;
  }
  if (winWidth <= 962) {
    vari = 0;
  }
  console.log(vari); // для демонстрации
}
variChange($(window).width()); // $(window).width() - ширина экрана
$(window).resize(function() {
  variChange($(window).width());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Если же вам не нужна поддержка IE9 и ниже, можете использовать [window.matchMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia):

```js
var vari;

function variChange(winWidth) {
  if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1200px)").matches) {
    vari = 10;
  }
  if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1200px)").matches) {
    vari = 5;
  }
  if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 962px)").matches) {
    vari = 0;
  }
  console.log(vari); // для демонстрации
}
variChange($(window).width()); // $(window).width() - ширина экрана
$(window).resize(function() {
  variChange($(window).width());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia

```
if(window.matchMedia('(max-width: 1200px)').matches)
{
  // код будет работать на экранах с шириной 1200 и меньше
}
```